# Blender 2.79 Adding Propeller to plane and moving whole object

Tags: modeling, animation

I created an airplane, added a propeller, It is connected but not joined. I want it to spin and move together with the plane. Appreciate any feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the propeller, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> on the plane. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to set the plane as a parent.

Comment: @corkj Obligatory reminder to accept ;)

Comment: Thank you. I had found the solution. Went on hiatus...